# Отличие OneToOne и ManyToOne(Foreignkey) field

Tags: python, django

Какое между ними различие? Я работал с many to one field, но узнал что существует oneToOne field и сколько бы не читал про них, непонимаю различия. Если можете то объясните понятно и другие виды( ManyToMany, ManyToOne, OneToOne)

Comment: из названия не понятно? o2o - один к одному строка в таблице 1 может иметь не более одной совпадающей строки в таблице 1. многие ко многим строка в таблице 1 может иметь много совпадающих строк в таблице 2, и наоборот. Пример автор-книга. У 1 автора может быть много кник. Как и у одной книги может быть несколько авторов. Один ко многим строка в таблице 1 может иметь много строк в таблице 2. Но строка в таблице 2 может иметь только одну строку в таблице 1. Пример Издательство кинотеатры и залы для фильмов. В кинотеатре может быть много залов. Но каждый зал принадлежит кинотеатру

Comment: Cpasibo bolshoye

Answer (score 1):

**ManyToManyField**

Объект первой модели может одновременно ассоциироваться с несколькими объектами второй модели. Например, один студент может посещать несколько курсов.

```
from django.db import models
 
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
 
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    courses = models.ManyToManyField(Course)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**OneToManyField**

Отношение один ко многим (One to Many)

Например, одна компания может выпускать несколько товаров

```
from django.db import models
 
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
 
class Product(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

Модель Company представляет производителя и является главной моделью, а модель Product представляет товар компании и является зависимой моделью.

Comment: вообще не верно 1 пункт описан.  В ващем описание нет никаого отличия от fk и m2m